# Using MPI_Gatherv with only a subset of all processes

Tags: mpi

I want to use `MPI_Gatherv` to collect data onto a single process.  The thing is, I don't need data from all other processes, just a subset of them.  The only communicator in the code is `MPI_COMM_WORLD`.  So, does every process in `MPI_COMM_WORLD` have to call `MPI_Gatherv`?  I have looked at the MPI standard and can't really make out what it is saying.  If all processes must make the call, can some of the values in `MPI_Gatherv's` "`recvcounts`" array be zero?  Or would there be some other way to signal to the root process which processes should be ignored?  I guess I could introduce another communicator, but for this particular problem that would be coding overkill.

Comment: All the ranks of the communicator must invoke a given collective subroutine. FWIW, some implementations might choose **not** to send/receive zero size messages, but that would not be portable.

Comment: You can make a new communicator for your subset, or check the `MPI_Neighbor_allgather` routine.